# cannot be resolved or is not a field

Tags: android

i would like to ask how can i solve this problem ..

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    textOut =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvGetInput);
    getInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput);
    Button ok = (Button) findViewById (R.id.bOk);
    ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

(the tvGetInput, etInput ,bOk has the error)
it says "cannot be resolve or is not a field"

Comment: Have you declare that all in main.xml file as id ?

Comment: Please post your main.xml file

Answer (score 5):

first , clean an re-build your project like this :

**Project ==> Clean ==> Check your project and press OK.**

second , verify your imports, if there is the `import android.R` , delete it , you should import the R of your project :

example : `import com.test.R;`

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Check your imports. There shan't be `android.R`. Also check if you declared these ids in your `main` layout. If all is ok, clean and build your project.